# AngularJS component for form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a form that contains different fields : input, select, select multiple, buttons. And I was wondering if it would be a good idea (and actually feasible) to create a component for this form, this component would be like a container that can contains all type of form fields (input, select, button, etc...).

I have put a sample of code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ODeci6ETIP3F8E9bqTo?p=preview), what I would like to do is to create a component for the form, in which I could insert how many other component I want (button, input, etc..).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="myInput.js"></script>
  <script src="myButton.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>My form</h2>
    <form role="form">
      <my-input label="Firstname"></my-input>
      <my-input label="Lastname"></my-input>
      <my-button label="Submit"></my-button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: obviously components are the ideal solution for such cases, especially if they have standalone logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to reuse the form in other parts of your code, I would say it would be a good idea to create it as a component.

Otherwise, it's just a matter of preference. Sometimes it can be nice to divide large portions of code into different files.

Edit: Plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/kyt9Q6L01r06dJXLDQZH?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <my-form></my-form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Edit 2: Updated the Plunker with an example of passing objects as attribute to the form

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <my-form inputlabels="inputs1"></my-form>
    <my-form inputlabels="inputs2"></my-form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanx so you confirm that it is feasible to create a form component that would be like a container of component?

Comment: @user3414662 Yes, if you plan on reusing the form or if you don't want to mix the form with your other code. This is a nice approach if you got a really large form with lots of functions and logic bound to it, then it will be easier for you to maintain in the long run if it has it's own files (that is, being used as a component).

Comment: Would you have some code to share because I don't know how to make a container component

Comment: I added code on plunker, can you please tell me how to put the form in a component in order it to be a container of components

Comment: @user3414662 I am not a 100 % what you are trying to do, but I have edited your Plunker as an example of how I would do it. Directives are like components, except they have access to more features. Please refer to this page for differences between components and directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to mention that I don't want to use directive. And also the solution you gave is not exactly what I am looking for because the content of the form will always be the same, and I want to be able to put different component in the form. In some views the form will contain only on button and only one input, in other views the form will conain 2 input and 2 button, etc...

Comment: @user3414662 Well, in that case you would have to pass some attributes to your MyForm component with options for inputs and buttons. I think that is an unnecessarily complicated approach and should be avoided.

Edit: But again, it all depends on how many times you are going to reuse this type of form.

Comment: Thank you @Prince John. I am using this form on more than 5 views, it is just the content of the form that changes between all my views but the style of the form is strictly the same in all the views

Comment: @user3414662 I updated the Plunker, it's an example of how you can pass arguments to the form to reuse the same form component with different inputs/buttons. It's not complete, but I think you'll understand how to progress from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark "Yes" to these two questions then you should build a component:

1. Is it reusable?
2. Does the form has a unique logic?